# How to fix shebang flags that are not recognized on some systems

Tags: python, shell, shebang

For some reason, the `-O` (optimized) flag is not recognized in the shebang line on a Red Hat Enterprise Server (release 5.3) that I access.  On other systems, the flag is recognized without any issue.

Executing the script below on OS X works fine. Recognition of the `-O` flag can be verified because it enables (when absent) or disables (when given) anything under the `if __debug__` conditional:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -O                                                                                                                                                                       

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if __debug__:
        print 'lots of debugging output on'

    print 'Fin'
```

Executing the same script on the RHE system result in:

> /usr/bin/env: python -O: No such file
>   or directory

Without the `-O` flag, the script executes normally on the RHE system (i.e., the `__debug__` built-in variable will be set to `True`).

Is there a cross-platform way to fix this issue?  Is there even a platform-specific way to fix the issue of flags on the shebang line to the python interpreter?

**Edit:**  Any other workarounds to setting the `__debug__` variable (without using shebang flags) interpreter-wide would also be interesting.

Comment: I vaguely remember a statement that you can't count on being able to pass more than one argument in the shebang, and `python` is that argument in `/usr/bin/env python`...

Comment: @delnan That was my fear also.  I was hoping there may be some clever way of quoting the ``python`` together with flags that would work but I haven't found anything.

Comment: just curious, but why do you use the env rather than point to python?

Comment: @uku because on some systems, I don't want the system version of python by default (often version < 2.4), I want to allow the user's ``$PATH`` settings to select a default python interpreter (e.g., an interpreter that may be in their home directory).

Comment: @Uku Loskit: Using `/usr/bin/env python` allows your script to run on different machines which have python installed in different places.

Comment: @Uku: So you don't have to go adjust every single script whenever the location of the python interpreter changes (or - very important for widely distributed stuff - when you install it on a machine which places the interpreter somewhere else) or you promote a different interpreter to the default version (a more propable situation when you use `python3`).

Comment: ok, that's what I thought. I haven't distributed anything like that myself, so I hadn't thought about it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about making a small shell script:

**pythono**:

```
#!/bin/sh    
/usr/bin/env python -O "$@"
```

Then change your script to use:

```
#!pythono
```

Also note that setting the environment variable `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` to a non-empty string is the same as using the `-O` flag. From the `man python` man page:

```
   PYTHONOPTIMIZE
          If this is set to a non-empty string it is equivalent to  specifying  the
          -O option. If set to an integer, it is equivalent to specifying -O multi‐
          ple times.
```

Comment: Er, if you can do that, you don't need `env`, you could just have `python -O "$@"`.

Comment: I like this.  I think this is the simplest thing that would fix my particular problem.

Comment: @unutbu I moved the `/usr/bin/env` call to inside `pythono`, since that's presumably what you meant.  There should be no need to call `/usr/bin/env pythono`, whereas the script could execute the wrong `python` if you don't call `env`.  Note `pythono` has to be on your `PATH` too.

Answer (score 5):

Some systems do not allow multiple arguments on a `#!`-style line. The "env hack" is not an officially recommended way of solving the path problem in any case - the preferred way to deal with this is to have the install rewrite the `#!` line to refer to `/bin/python`, `/usr/bin/python`, as appropriate for the system.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html

Comment: Good to know also.  Thanks Random.

Answer (score 4):

To extend slightly what [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu) said, you have the option of initializing `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` at runtime. This works for all modern shells:

```
% PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1 foo.py
Fin
```

And for completeness:

```
% foo.py
lots of debugging output on
Fin
```

Comment: Thanks.  Being able to enable/disable on a per-script basis is even better.

Comment: You know it! This is a *nix-wide thing, and not specific to Python.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
''''exec python -O -- "$0" ${1+"$@"} # '''
if __name__ == '__main__':

    if __debug__:
        print 'lots of debugging output on'

    print 'Fin'
# vi: syntax=python
```

Comment: Nice polyglot script!

Answer (score 0):

Change the shebang to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -O
```

This assumes, of course, that the Python interpreter is installed as `/usr/bin/python`; otherwise, adjust as needed.

See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [my answer to it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you are using `#!/usr/bin/env python` is so that you can leverage the `PATH` to find your favorite version of `python`.

If that is NOT the case and you are fine using `/usr/bin/python` (or some other hard coded path to the interpreter), then the most direct solution should be to use `#!/usr/bin/python -O` as suggested by @keith-thompson

However, assuming you want to continue relying on `PATH` to find `python`, you will need to invoke a shell in order to get control over the command line:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec python -O - "$@" <<EOF

# ... your python code starts here ...
if __name__ == '__main__':

    if __debug__:
        print 'lots of debugging output on'

    print 'Fin'
# ... your python code ends here ...

EOF
```

This is similar to the `pythono` solution suggested by @unutbu except that it doesn't rely on the `PATH` to find the intermediate script which means it is slightly better performance and slightly more secure.

This solution has the drawback of mixing two languages which means you cannot simply say `python myscript.py` to execute your code with `__debug__` set to `True`.  If it is your intention to be able to execute the code sometimes directly via the script (e.g. `~/bin/myscript.py`) with `-O` turned on but other times to run the script by hand in a debugging environment (e.g. `python ~/bin/myscript.py`) with `-O` turned off, then I believe your best options are to use expert tricks like that proposed by @ade-yu or to use the simple `pythono` option suggested by @unutbu.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You will want to use "EOF" (with quotes) to avoid having the shell try to interpret the contents of the heredoc (like if there is $foo in the text).

Answer (score -1):

Just make your shebang without a flag; then, execute the environment again with the flag passing it to a heredoc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

/usr/bin/env python -O <<EOF
code goes here...
...
EOF
```

Basically have your terminating EOF at the end of the file.

Comment: `/usr/bin/env python -O <<EOF` is invalid syntax and indeed this results in a `SyntaxError` for me. -1

Comment: This isn't that bad with a small change to fix the fact that you are trying to run shell code with the python interpeter.  Instead make it a shell script:  `#!/bin/sh` on the shebang line, then `exec python -O << EOF` on the next line (note the `exec` and no need for `/usr/bin/env`).

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you want to continue using `#!/usr/bin/env`, you can take advantage of the facts that

1. `python` has environment variable equivalents for its command-line switches
2. `env` can be used to set environment variables before running the command

Putting these together, you get the following solution:

`#!/usr/bin/env PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1 python`

You asked for "cross-platform".  This only works for Unix (e.g. Linux, OS X, etc.).  I can't speak for Windows. I would expect this to work under `cygwin` as well but YMMV.

Comment: This runs into the same issue where only the first argument in the she-bang line is guaranteed to be passed to the interpreter, e. g. on Linux this results in an infinite recursion of `/usr/bin/env` invocations because `PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1 python` is interpreted as a single argument. -1

Comment: @DavidFoerster's comment seems valid - at least I can reproduce the problem on freebsd as well.  Maybe a correction would be useful in this answer.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @david-foerster.  I tested on OS X where it worked fine and didn't realize that on Linux it is literally exec ` '/usr/bin/env' 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1 python' _script_` which obviously misses the mark.  I will propose a new answer.